# table-layout: fixed issue with column widths

Tags: google-chrome, html-table, tablelayout

We're using the CSS `table-layout: fixed` property for our mobile app. (I don't recall the full reason, but I believe it had to do with enabling word wrapping of some sorts)...

I've run into an issue where we need to size one of the two columns of the two column table. Not a big deal, usually we do this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>        
    <tr>
      <th width="20%">hello world</th>
      <td>hello world</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That works fine.

However, if we need to create a row that spans both columns BEFORE this one:

```
<table>
  <tbody>   
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">hello world</th>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
      <th width="20%">hello world</th>
      <td>hello world</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What happens, at least in Chrome, is that the two columns snap to 50% widths. I have a jsbin sample here:

http://jsbin.com/ejovut/3

Is this normal behavior? A Chrome bug? A way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a bug.  `table-layout:fixed` means that the browser is allowed to optimize table-layout computations by assuming only the first row and column specifications matter.  In particular, it does **NOT** need to inspect and do layout computations on later table content, which can make a large difference in layout performance.

The right solution is to use the `<col>` and `<colgroup>` elements to explicitly specify column widths, rather than using the first row.

Comment: Sorry to appear dense, but is the solution to *not* use table-layout:fixed? Or to use col and colgroup in addition to table-layout:fixed if this fixed "word wrapping"? (TBH I don't know why table-layout would be used at all in this example and simply removing it would solve the problem?

Comment: `table-layout: fixed` can be necessary for breaking long words (see http://jsbin.com/utifiy/2/edit).  In general, if you need precise layout control, the `fixed` value gives you that whereas the default does more magic: but you need to replace that magic sizing with *something* - so that's why you need to either explicitly size the **first row** or `col` element specifications.  The OP's problem was that if the first row has cells that span columns, you *cannot* declare the size of the columns on the cells, so the solution is to use `col`-based sizing.

Answer (score -1):

first table row should contain all 
also, Chrome bugs does not allow to use  for this.

Comment: So, this is a known Chrome bug and the workaround is to make sure there is a blank first row that contains each individual TD?

Comment: yes, with specified "width", it is not only for Chrome, but also for FF and IE, although IE and FF allows to specify 'width" of each cell with <col> tags

Comment: "Chrome bugs not allows to use for this" - which bugs exactly?