# IE8 excludes columns from tbody

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-8, tablelayout

I'm having a problem displaying multiple tables on a page.

The table code is quite simple. The CSS sets out the width of each td by % and the `table-layout` is `fixed`.

It seems like the problem is caused because the first table has X amount of columns, but the second has X + 3. This causes the last columns to be excluded from the table body.

[image]

When inspecting the DOM, I can see that the last columns on the right are existing outside of the table body (in design) but exist inside the table body in the code.

[image]

If I remove `table-layout:fixed` from the css, the tables overlap, but it does apply the correct CSS background-colors etc. to the final columns. This also happens if I leave the table-layout as is, but remove the width:100% attribute. So it seems it could also be an issue where the fixed table widths are being maintained throughout all tables since the first one.

I believe this could be strongly related to this [SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134194/table-layout-fixed-issue-with-column-widths)

[image]

Any ideas?

```
<div>
    <table>
        // th elements
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <table>
        // th elements
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>1</td>
               <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @chovy this project is for a large corporation. I think fixing my issue may be easier than upgrading all of the companies machines.

Comment: you could make a jsfiddle with some data ... so people can play ...

Comment: old way of thinking. evergreen now. nothing else. i care not if < IE11 doesn't work.

Comment: Its more "national security" than an "old way of thinking"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was sort of what I had expected.

It turns out that IE (and some other browsers) will base all table layouts based on the first row of the first table.

So if you have multiple tables on one page with varying amounts of columns, you could end up in a situation where any extra columns are left hanging off the end of the table, as mine was.

Some people have suggested using `colgroup` and `col` attributes above the `thead`, but I found that this didnt work for me.

Instead, I created a hidden `thead` above my original, containing the maximum amount of columns required.

```
    <thead>
        <tr hidden="hidden">
            <th span="1"></th>
            <th span="3"></th>
            <th span="3"></th>
            <th span="3"></th>
            <th span="1"></th>
            <th span="2"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
        // My actual table headers
    </thead>
```